# erlang: string strip multiple characters

Tags: string, erlang

I see erlang has the `string:strip` method and you can also specify which character to strip on the third parameter:

```
string:strip("...Hello.....", both, $.).
```

But, how can I define multiple characters to strip? so for example if I had `".;.;..Hello...;.."` I want to strip it to `"Hello"`.

Comment: @eLRuLL , this? lists:filter(fun(X)-> not lists:member(X,RemCh) end,".;.;..Hello...;..").

Comment: Maybe you can use `re:replace`.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm: It would remove characters also inside of string so it is not working solution.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil ,  thanks,fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your own `strip/3` version with a list of stripping characters support is not as hard as it looks like:

```
strip(S, left, Ds) ->
    lstrip(S, Ds);
strip(S, right, Ds) ->
    rstrip(S, Ds);
strip(S, both, Ds) ->
    rstrip(lstrip(S, Ds), Ds).

lstrip([], _) -> [];
lstrip([H|T] = S, Ds) ->
    case lists:member(H, Ds) of
        true  -> lstrip(T, Ds);
        false -> S
    end.

rstrip([], _) -> [];
rstrip([H|T], Ds) ->
    case rstrip(T, Ds) of
        [] ->
            case lists:member(H, Ds) of
                true  -> [];
                false -> [H]
            end;
        S -> [H|S]
    end.
```

Note `lists:member/2` is BIF and this version is written in a way to minimise heap usage.

Answer (score 1):

The following function which takes a list  L of characters to strip from string S will achieve your objective:

```
stripm(S, both, L) -> S1 = stripm(S,L),
    lists:reverse(stripm(lists:reverse(S1),L)).

stripm([], _L) -> [];
stripm(S = [H|T], L) ->
    case lists:member(H, L) of
        true -> 
            S1 = string:strip(T,left,H),
            stripm(S1, L);
        false ->
            S
    end.
```